# Getting ressource from /res in dependency

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

Currently playing with Android .aar files and making libs. If i have made a style in a .aar file and included this .aar file into my project that i'm working on. How would i go about acessing the /res/ in my manifest and set the theme to the theme style made in the .aar (dependency)?

Comment: Look at *Syntax* here. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html  You can include the package name

Comment: currently got it to work with code, but more interested in doing it within the manifest: sitting with android:theme="?first/styles/KT_slide_theme"
but it seems it cant find the package name first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply as documentation mention

in Java

```
[<package_name>.]R.<resource_type>.<resource_name>
```

in Xml

```
@[<package_name>:]<resource_type>/<resource_name>
```